# How do I show these properties of maps between vector spaces relate to the properties of linear independence/spanning?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $V\neq 0$, a Vector Space over a field $F$. Let $S \subset V$ be a non-empty set. Consider the following properties of $S$:

(1) For any Vector Space $W$ over $F$, any map $f : S \to W$ extends to a linear map from $V$ to $W$.

(2) For any Vector Space $W$ over $F$ any two linear maps $f,g : V \to W$ satisfying $f(s) = g(s)$ for all $s \in S$, we have $f(v)=g(v)$ $\forall v \in V$.

(3) $S$ is linearly independent.

(4) The span of $S$ is $V$.

Then prove that (1) implies (3) and (2) implies (4).

MY ATTEMPT:

I am aware of the fact that every linearly independent set containing finite list of vectors can be extended to form a basis of a finite dimensional vector space $V$. But this result might fail to give me a conclusion here, since the vector space can contain infinite list of vectors as well! Also there exist another thought as if I consider any arbitrary set $S$ then the choices of it being linearly dependent or independent are equivalent, at the same time it need not be necessary that Span of $S$ will be $V$. Any help?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is a neat exercise at the heart of this problem, but the problem's presentation (through no fault of yours!) is pretty bad IMHO. "Elucidate the relationship", as an instruction, is vague and poorly-defined. It looks like it means that you should find which of the four conditions imply one another, but this would make the answer provided incomplete, as $(1)$ is actually **equivalent** to $(3)$, and similarly for $(2)$ and $(4)$. This requires four proofs to show. In addition, you'll need two counterexamples to show that $(1)$ (or $(3)$) is not equivalent to $(2)$ (or $(4)$)...

Comment: That's six proofs/constructions to do this question properly, a fact which seems lost on whomever wrote the answer you were given! Also, I'm 99% sure that whomever set the question meant to include that $V$ is finite-dimensional. It's not that the question is much more difficult in general, but it requires slightly heavier machinery, like Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: The question, as it stands, is too broad, due to the unexpectedly large scope of the problem you're quoting. If I were you, I would narrow it down to simply showing that $(1) \implies (3)$ (or perhaps that they're equivalent), and ask $(2) \implies (4)$ in a follow-up question.

Comment: @TheoBendit edited to improve the problem's presentation!

Comment: Any thoughts about finite-dimensions? Would you accept an answer that assumed $V$ was finite-dimensional? Or are you looking for an answer in possibly infinite dimensions?

Comment: As the question makes no comment over V being finite or infinite dimensional, the assumption will answer half of the question only. No thoughts over infinite? You can quote your answer being a special case, it will reduce half of the load!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $S$ is linearly dependent. That is, there exists some $x \in S$, $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in S \setminus \{x\}$, and $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \in F$ such that
$$x = \alpha_1 x_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n x_n.$$
Consider a map $f : S \to F$ that maps everything to $0$, except $x$, which it maps to $1$. Suppose $T : V \to F$ is a linear map extending $f$. Then,
$$1 = Tx = \alpha_1 Tx_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n Tx_n = 0,$$
a contradiction. Thus, no such $T$ exists, so $\lnot (3) \implies \lnot(1)$, i.e. $(1) \implies (3)$.

Proving $(2) \implies (4)$ is where it would be handy to assume finite-dimensions, or at least assume you were more comfortable with infinite-dimensions. It's not harder, as all the standard results still hold, they just require different proofs, and the knowledge of how bases work in infinite dimensions. Essentially, we argue like this:

- If $S$ does not span, then $\exists v \in V \setminus \operatorname{span} S$.
- Reduce $S$ to a (Hamel) basis $B$ of $\operatorname{span} S$ (This still works; you need Zorn's lemma).
- Show $B \cup \{v\}$ is linearly independent.
- Extend $B \cup \{v\}$ to a (Hamel) basis $C$ of $V$ (more Zorn's lemma).
- Take the map $f : C \to F$ that maps everything to $0$, except $v$ which it maps to $1$, and extend it linearly to $V$ (you can do this uniquely with Hamel bases, just like in finite-dimensions, but once again, you need Zorn's lemma).
- Such a map agrees with the $0$ map on $\operatorname{span} B = \operatorname{span} S$, and hence agrees on $S$, but is not the same as the $0$ map, due to what it does to $C$. Thus, $\lnot (4) \implies \lnot (2)$.

I'm reluctant to go into more detail than this, because I don't want to re-explain the theory to you from the perspective of infinite-dimensions. If you're happy with finite-dimensions, then my outline above still works, and should work within the framework of finite-dimensions that you've (hopefully) covered so far.